# What is area of shaded region?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, area

Suppose the side length $a$ of the square is 10mm.
A circle is tangent to all four sides of the square. And two quarter-circles with the same radius of 10mm have centers on the opposite vertices.

[image]

It may be easier to view it in the picture on the right.

What’s the area of shaded region? Using some trigonometrical calculation, I got a complex formula

$$S=\left[\frac{1}{2}(\pi -\arccos(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}))+\sqrt{2}\sin(\arccos(\frac{5\sqrt{2}}{8}))-2\arccos(\frac{5\sqrt{2}}{8})\right]a^2$$
which gives 29.276$mm^2$. The way is far from beautiful. Don’t know if there are any simpler ways to do that? Is there any principles that I am not aware of?

Thank you.

Comment: Please, tell us more. What have you tried? What would you like to try, if you knew how? What's stopping you?

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide some more info about your question, such as how is the ellipse-like shape constructed.

Comment: I believe that it is a circle tangent to all 4 sides and two quarter-circles with radius $a$ that have centers on opposite vertices.

Comment: @AjayMishra typo. It's mm²

Comment: @ETS1331 thank u. I quote yours.

Comment: Are you sure your answer is right?

Answer (score 2):

The area can be expressed in various inverse trigonometric functions, with below the most concise (assuming unit square)

$$\frac14\left(\sqrt{7}-\cos^{-1}\frac{393}{4096}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\hskip 1.9 in$[image]

**Method 1**: Via geometry

Here $GC = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}, GH = \frac{a}{2}, CH = a$

By using cosine rule, angle $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be found. Now area of sector $CHI$ is $A = \cfrac{\alpha a^2 }{2}$,
area of $ \Delta CHG=A_1 =  \cfrac{ \sin \alpha a^2}{2 \sqrt{2} } \Rightarrow $ Area of figure $CHGI$ would be $2A_1$ .Now, area of figure $GHI = A_3 = A - 2A_1$.

From simple geometry $\angle HGI = \gamma = 2 \pi - 2 \beta$, now area of sector $GHI = A_4 = \cfrac{\gamma a^2 }{8} $  which implies area of shaded portion on the right is $A_4 - A_3$, hence total area is $2(A_4 - A_3)$

**Method 2**: Via calculus with some coordinate geometry

You can setup the system on cartesian coordinates with origin$(0,0)$ at the center of smaller circle $C_1$ , $- x$-axis along segment $CG$, and considering only one bigger circle $C_2$ , its centre would be at $ ( - a/ \sqrt{2} , 0 )$.

Equation of the circles are:

$$ \begin{align} C_1 & :  x^2 + y^2 = \cfrac{a^2}{4} \\
                 C_2 & : \bigg(x + \cfrac{a}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg)^2 + y^2 = a^2 
\end{align} $$

On solving $x = \cfrac{a}{4 \sqrt{2}}$, which is the $x$-coordinate of point of intersection. I hope now you can take from here. Can you?

Comment: Only thing you have to calculate is $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure your solution is incorrect. I believe the correct value of the area is given by
$$2\left(\overbrace{(2r)^2}^{\text{area of square}}-\overbrace{\frac{\pi(2r)^2}{4}}^{\text{area of larger quarter circle}}-\overbrace{(r^2-\frac{\pi r^2}{4})}^{\text{area between smaller circle}\\\,\,\,\,\,\text{ and lower left corner}}-2c\right)$$
where $c$ is the area between the bottom edge of the square and where the intersection of the two circles form an 'X' shape. The value of $c$ can be calculated by the following integrals
$$c=\int_r^{(3+\sqrt{7})r/4}\left(r-\sqrt{r^2-(x-r)^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x+\int_{(3+\sqrt{7})r/4}^{2r}\left(2r-\sqrt{4r^2-(x-2r)^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$
where the two integrands are the equations of the bottom half of each circle in question. The final value for the area highlighted in blue simplifies to
$$r^2\left(\sqrt{7}+\frac{3\pi}{2}+4\arctan{\left(\frac{2+\sqrt{7}}{3}\right)}-16\arctan{\left(\frac{4+\sqrt{7}}{9}\right)}\right)$$