# Find area of shaded region between circles inscribed inside a square

Tags: area

Find the area of the shaded region such that the measure of a side of the square is $x$ unit.

[image]

Here is my plan and incomplete solution:

Step 1: I need to subtract the area of the circle from the area square and divide it by $4$. I denote the resulting area as $A_1$

$A_1 = \dfrac{x^2(4-π)}{16}$ square units

Step 2: Next is I need to subtract the area of a quarter circle with radius $x$ unit from the square. I denoted this resulting area as $A_2$.

$A_2 = x^2\left(1-\dfrac{π}{4}\right)$ square units

Step 3: My next plan is to subtract $A_1$ from $A_2$. The result is denoted as $A_3$.

$A_3 = \dfrac{3x^2}{16}(4-π)$ square units

I was stock in step 3. I know that I still need to remove a certain portion to get the area of the shaded region.

Comment: What class are you taking?  What methods are you allowed to use?

Comment: Hi @saulspatz! I am not taking any classes. Every week, I am looking for some challenging math questions for me and trying to solve it as my hobby.

Comment: Please share your solution in the simplest way that you can. Any solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: Okay, then what methods do you know about?  Can we use trigonometry, calculus?

Comment: Please share the trigonometry version of the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the area of this shaded region?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3265394/what-is-the-area-of-this-shaded-region) See also [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3613610/409). There may be others.

Comment: Hi @Blue! Thank you for sharing this solution. I would like to kindly change my question statement and find a possible solution using calculus.

Comment: @MKA: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3265504/409) uses calculus. In any case, if you want to specify the type of solution you seek, [edit the question itself](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3621358/edit). Comments are easily overlooked.